# Are there any non parametric tests to check for Pareto data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, pareto-distribution

I'm in search of a non parametric test to check whether my data are Pareto distributed, but I couldn't find a proper reference for it. I'm using R to simulate these so if there's any R in built test, would be acceptable for the moment. But I prefer to construct my own R functions so it would be highly appreciated if I could get a good reference which has a non parametric statistical test to check whether the data are Pareto distributed.

Comment: Your question appears to be based on a mistaken premise; you don't generally need to know the parameter *values* to conduct a parametric test.

Comment: Thanks for denoting. I'll edit the question

Comment: The edit simply replaces the original problem with a new one; you certainly don't need to know population parameters to estimate them (that's why you'd estimate them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lFirst let us note a few simplifications that will make life easier:

(a) if $X_i$ are iid Pareto $(c,\alpha)$, with $\alpha$ being the index and $c$ the left bound, then $Y_i=\log(X_i)$ are shifted exponential $(\log(c),\alpha)$ (where $\alpha$ is rate, not scale);

(b) If $Y_i,i=1,2,...,n$ are shifted exponential, then $Z_k=Y_k-Y_{(1)}\,,$ $k=1,...,n-1$ (dropping the Z-value that would be exactly 0 and relabelling the rest) are iid exponential($\alpha$); we may call that smaller sample size $m$. That is, if we take logs and subtract the smallest observation from the rest, we have reduced the problem to a simple test of 1-parameter exponentiality with unknown coefficient.

So let us focus on tests for this simpler problem.

There are numerous tests for exponentiality with unknown parameter; indeed its an issue addressed in several posts already on site. [You should be careful not to simply apply a test for a fully specified distribution to this situation.]

For example, Lilliefors (1969)[1] constructed one such, based on the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with estimated parameter. We needn't restrict ourselves to the sample sizes covered there, since the test is trivial to simulate at whatever sample size we wish; we have the advantage over Lilliefors of having accuracy to far more computing power on a cheap laptop than he could access in the 60s.

This is not automatically the best choice; indeed you probably want to focus on the tail, in which case a modified version of the Anderson-Darling test (to account for parameter estimation) might be a better choice, or perhaps one based on a similar idea to the Shapiro-Francia test. These alternatives are briefly discussed in the first link below.

Numerous other tests (and perhaps more importantly, diagnostic displays) are noted in answers and comments in [*How do I check if my data fits an exponential distribution*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76994/how-do-i-check-if-my-data-fits-an-exponential-distribution) and some useful points are made in [*What are the standard statistical tests to see if data follows exponential or normal distributions?*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32061/what-are-the-standard-statistical-tests-to-see-if-data-follows-exponential-or-no).

---

An issue worth keeping in mind is that failure to reject a Pareto with a goodness of fit test doesn't indicate that the data were drawn from a Pareto distribution, nor even that some other simple two-parameter family might not fit even better. If alternatives are realistic possibilities, you should consider their plausibility as well; this will help avoid the common-but-mistaken tendency to believe the model you started with simply because you lack evidence against it.

---

However, we should beware -- it's rather easy to answer the wrong question with goodness of fit tests and be led astray. Some of the points made in [*Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2501/805) (particularly ones made by Harvey Motulsky, which I directly link to) apply just as well to this situation, *mutatis mutandis*.

[1]: Lilliefors, H. (1969), "On the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test for the exponential distribution with mean unknown", Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 64, pp. 387–389.